# Precisely sizing an object?

Tags: objects, scale

I'm trying to port some models for a mapping software (Hammer), and 1 meter in Blender is equal to 1 unit in Hammer (Otherwise it's extremely hard to adjust door frames, etc.). Is there a way to resize objects in a precise way so it's approximately x meters on each side and somehow seeing their current size? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I also used hammer and blender. And had the same problems first. when you click n to oben the sidebar there is a tab where you can change the size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy.
Just press n while in viewport and a sidebar will open.
Click on item tab in it.
There will be written the scale,rotation and location of the selected object along with dimentions.
By default,the dimentions will show the x,y and z dimentions of the selected object in terms of meter.
Scale the object will the dimentions are of x meters in z